# Nodejs: make a GET request with users parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express, server

I'm new in nodejs. I'm making a express server. I recive some parameter by url, and I wnat to make a request to another server with the parameters in the recived url.

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser  = require("body-parser"),
methodOverride = require("method-override");
request = require('request');
Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());

var router = express.Router();

app.use(router);

router.get('/get_metric_names_by_pattern', function(req, res) {

   console.log('get_metric_names_by_pattern '+req.url);

   console.log(req.query.pattern);
   //console.log(req.parameters);

   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   var client = new Client();
   var salida;


   console.log(req.params.name);
   //Creamos la variable para los parametros
   var args = {
        parameters: {pattern: "OEE"}
        //headers: { "test-header": "client-api" }
    };



    console.log(args);
    console.log(args.parameters.pattern);
   client.get('http:// localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=:pattern', req.query.pattern,


    //http://   localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=OEE

    function (data, response) {
        //console.log(args.parameters.pattern);
        console.log(data);
        //var pattern = req.query.pattern;
        //data = data.toString('utf8'); //Transformamos los datos a string para que los reconozca el navegador
        //console.log(data);
      salida = JSON.parse(data);
      //console.log("Datos:", salida.date);
      res.send(salida); //Lo enviamos al navegador
      //console.log(salida);
    });
});
```

I do recive the paramteter from the client (in this case 'OEE') **but I find no way to insert that string into**  client.get('http://  localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=:pattern', req.query.pattern, .

The request should look like the commented line under that one ( //http://localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=OEE) and from that request I'm recibing a json, just like this :

```
["PanelPC0_OEE", "empacadora1.OEE", "empacadora1.OEEE", "empacadora1.OEE_Avaible", "empacadora1.OEE_Performance", "empacadora1.OEE_quality"]
```

The console.log look like this:

> node servicio.js
>
> Servidor corriendo en: http:// localhost:3000
>
> get_metric_names_by_pattern /get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=OEE
>
> OEE
>
> undefined
>
> { parameters: { pattern: 'OEE' } }
>
> OEE
>
> Buffer 5b 5d

and it should look like :

> node servicio.js
>
> Servidor corriendo en: http://  localhost:3000
>
> get_metric_names_by_pattern /get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=OEE
>
> OEE
>
> undefined
>
> { parameters: { pattern: 'OEE' } }
>
> OEE
>
> Buffer 5b 22 50 61 6e 65 6c 50 43 30 5f 4f 45 45 22 2c 20 22 74 65 61 6d 66 6f
>   6f 64 73 2e 62 6f 67 6f 74 61 2e 6d 61 72 67 61 72 69 6e 61 73 2e 65 6d 70 61 ..
>   .

Please, I need to know how to insert that parameter into the new url. Sorry if this post is to long or obvius. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I misread but isn't it simply a case of `'http:// localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=' + req.query.pattern`?

Comment: That would make a SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input @mrwillihog

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client), to insert a parameter or argument you should use:

> ${param}

like this example:

```
var args = {
    path: { "id": 120, "arg1": "hello", "arg2": "world" },
    parameters: { arg1: "hello", arg2: "world" },
    headers: { "test-header": "client-api" }
};


client.get("http://remote.site/rest/json/${id}/method?arg1=${arg1}&arg2=${arg2}", args,
    function (data, response) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(response);
    });
```

so in your case you should try to use:

```
var args = {
    parameters: { pattern: req.query.pattern },
};

client.get('http:// localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern=${pattern}', args,
    function(data, response){

    });
```

Comment: I've tried that one, but is the same result . @jack.the.ripper

Answer (score 0):

although it is not pretty... the comment of @mrwillihog gave me this idea, wich actually works!

```
urln = 'http://localhost:8000/get_metric_names_by_pattern/?pattern='+req.query.pattern;

console.log(urln);

client.get(urln,    function (data, response) { });
```